# Do watch the episode Vs. Watch the episode

Tags: do-support

I want to know the difference between these two sentences,, when should I use?

1. Do watch the episode
2. Watch the episode

Answer (score 3):

"Watch the episode" is a simple command. It is direct and so could be rude, depending on the context.

"Do watch the episode" is rather rarer. It is a request, normally used in a particular context. Consider:

> Here is your cup of tea, and do take a biscuit.

In this example I know 1) Most people like to have a biscuit with their tea, but 2) people will politely refuse to take a biscuit.  So I have to politely insist that they actually take a biscuit, because I want to make them happy.

Saying "Do watch the episode" is a way of politely insisting that you should watch the episode.